# How to speed up Sequelize findAndCountAll?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have pagination made with Sequelize

router.js

```
router.post('/getall', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { q, page, limit, order_by, order_direction } = req.query;
    const { candidate, position, filters } = req.body

      let include = [
        {
          model: SortedLvl,
          where: {
            lvl: filters.jobLvl.name,
            months: { [Op.gte]: filters.jobMinExp.value },
          },
        },
        {
          model: SortedLastJob,
          where: { jobposition: filters.jobType.name }
        },
        {
          model: SortedSkills,
        }
      ]
      let search = {};
      let order = [];

      let filterCandidate = {}
      if (candidate) {
        if (candidate != undefined) {
          t = candidate.split(/[ ,]+/)
          let arr = new Array()
          // console.log('t', t);
          t.map((el, index) => {
            console.log('el', el);
            if (typeof el == 'number') {
              arr.push({ first_name: { [Op.iLike]: `%` + `${el}` + `%` } }, { last_name: { [Op.iLike]: `%` + `${el}` + `%` } });
            } else {
              arr.push({ first_name: { [Op.iLike]: `%` + `%${el}%` + `%` } }, { last_name: { [Op.iLike]: `%` + `%${el}%` + `%` } });
            }
          });

          filterCandidate = {
            [Op.or]: arr
          };
        }
      }

      let filterPosition = {}
      if (position) {
        if (position != undefined) {
          filterPosition = { position: { [Op.iLike]: `%${position}%` } }
        }
      }

      if (filterCandidate.length > 0 || filterPosition.length > 0) {
        search = { where: { ...(filterCandidate || []), ...(filterPosition || []) } }
      }

      console.log('search', search);
      console.log('candidate', filterCandidate);
      console.log('position', filterPosition);

      if (order_by && order_direction) {
        order.push([order_by, order_direction]);
      }

      const transform = (records) => {
        return records.map(record => {
          return {
            id: record.id,
            name: record.name,
            date: moment(record.createdAt).format('D-M-Y H:mm A')
          }
        });
      }
      const products = await paginate(Candidate, page, limit, search, order, include);

      return res.json({
        success: true,
        // message: '',
        data: products
      })
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Failed to fetch products', error);
    return res.status(500).send({
      success: false,
      message: 'Failed to fetch products'
    })
  }
});
```

paginate.js

```
const paginate = async (model, pageSize, pageLimit, search = {}, order = [], include, transform, attributes, settings) => {
  try {
    const limit = parseInt(pageLimit, 10) || 10;
    const page = parseInt(pageSize, 10) || 1;

    // create an options object
    let options = {
      offset: getOffset(page, limit),
      limit: limit,
      distinct: true,
      include: include,
    };

    // check if the search object is empty
    if (Object.keys(search).length) {
      options = { ...options, ...search };
    }

    if (attributes && attributes.length) {
      options['attributes'] = attributes;
    }

    if (order && order.length) {
      options['order'] = order;
    }

    let data = await model.findAndCountAll(options);
  
    if (transform && typeof transform === 'function') {
        data = transform(data.rows);
    }



      return {
        previousPage: getPreviousPage(page),
        currentPage: page,
        nextPage: getNextPage(page, limit, count),
        total: count,
        limit: limit,
        data: data.rows
      }
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

const getOffset = (page, limit) => {
  return (page * limit) - limit;
}

const getNextPage = (page, limit, total) => {
  if ((total / limit) > page) {
    return page + 1;
  }

  return null
}

const getPreviousPage = (page) => {
  if (page <= 1) {
    return null
  }
  return page - 1;
}


module.exports = paginate;
```

First problem - on queries with included models sometimes it response with wrong count
and also it is so slow

Please, help me with solving this issue

Thank you

I tried use separate: true, required: true and etc - I just get empty arrays on included

Comment: Use Sequelize indexes to property whatever you want, and also add indexes in the table columns.

Answer (score 0):

In your sequelize request there are lots of json query. Mysql cant create directly index your json fields. You can create a referance your query property like below and after that you can add a index for reference column.
And change your referance column as created reference. Also you can create mysql index another requests columns.

```
ALTER TABLE [table_name] ADD COLUMN email VARCHAR(255)
  GENERATED ALWAYS as (properties->>"$.[jsonObjectName].[jsonProperty]");

ALTER TABLE [table_name] ADD INDEX email ([jsonProperty]) USING BTREE;
```

Comment: I use postgres via sequelize actually(

Comment: This is no problem you can make it directly SQL code. It will not affect the your models.

Comment: So, can you please a bit explain? Should I add index in every table to speed up my queries? And for exp, i have tables 
Candidate.init({
    last_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    first_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    middle_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    money: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    phone: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    position: DataTypes.TEXT,
    company: DataTypes.TEXT,
    photo_url: DataTypes.TEXT,
    birthday: DataTypes.DATE,
    hunt: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Candidate',
  });

and

Comment: SortedLvl.init({
    candidate_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    lvl: DataTypes.TEXT,
    months: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'SortedLvl',
  });

the first one include (join) sortedlvl table via candidate_id

to which and how i can implement index?